# Cannot send an empty message 50006 when using multipart Laravel Http post

Tags: laravel, post, discord, multipartform-data

I am getting this error when trying to send a message to a Discord webhook.

```
{"message": "Cannot send an empty message", "code": 50006}
```

I've read the [discord documentation](https://discord.com/developers/docs/reference#uploading-files) on sending images, and can honestly not see what I'm doing wrong.

Here's the code I'm running:

```
Http::withHeaders([
    'Content-Type' => 'multipart/form-data; boundary=--abcdefghijklmnop'
])
    ->asMultipart()
    ->post(
        $this->webhookUrl,
        [
            [
                'name' => 'payload_json',
                'contents' => '{
  "content": "Hello, World!",
  "embeds": [{
    "title": "Hello, Embed!",
    "description": "This is an embedded message.",
    "thumbnail": {
      "url": "attachment://image1.jpg"
    },
    "image": {
      "url": "attachment://image2.jpg"
    }
  }],
  "attachments": [{
      "id": 0,
      "description": "Image of a cute little cat",
      "filename": "image1.jpg"
  }, {
      "id": 1,
      "description": "Rickroll gif",
      "filename": "image2.jpg"
  }]
}',
                'headers' => [
                    'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
                ]
            ],
            [
                'name' => 'image1.jpg',
                'contents' => 'data:image/jpeg;base64,[[encoded image]]',
                'headers' => [
                    'Content-Type' => 'image/jpeg',
                ]
            ],
            [
                'name' => 'image2.jpg',
                'contents' => 'data:image/jpeg;base64,[[encoded image]]',
                'headers' => [
                    'Content-Type' => 'image/jpeg',
                ]
            ]
        ];
    );
```

As you can see, this is basically the message they use in their documentation as an example and I've just translated it to be sent with the `Http` facade.

What am I missing?